# Expanding object properties in powershell class

Tags: powershell, class

i am creating a PS class and want to expand the properties of a certain object, i did this

```
Class SchulKlasse 
{
[int]$JahrGang 
[int]$schulerAnzahl
[string]$KlassenLehrer
[string]$schulForm
[string]$Name 
[int]$klassenRaum 
[string]$Gebäude 
[string]$Fächer


Schulklasse ([string]$Name, $Gebäude, $SchulerAnzahl,$Fächer, $JahrGang, $KlassenLehrer, $schulForm, $KlassenRaum)
{
    $this.Name = $Name
    $this.Gebäude = $Gebäude
    $this.schulerAnzahl = $SchulerAnzahl
    $this.Fächer = $Fächer
    $this.JahrGang = $JahrGang
    $this.KlassenLehrer = $KlassenLehrer
    $this.schulForm = $schulForm
    $this.klassenRaum = $KlassenRaum
}


}


$newKlassTest = [SchulKlasse]::new('Erfolg','B20','2015','Mathe,Wirtschaft,Sport','1996','H.Müller','GrundSchule','13')
```

now based on the users choice i want to expand the $klassenLehrer Object

```
$newKlassTest
$test = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$test | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Lehrer -Value $newKlassTest.KlassenLehrer
$test | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Nachname -Value **** 
$test | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Vorname -Value ****
$test | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Kenntnisse -Value "master in it management"
$test | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Faecher -Value "Datenbanken,Vernetzte Systeme"
$test | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Geburtsdatum  -Value 1979
$test | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Verfügbarkeit -Value "Montags bis Donnerstags"

$Anfrage = Read-host "Möchten Sie mehr Informationen über den Klassenlehrer wissen? j,n"
if ($Anfrage -eq 'j')
{
$test
}
else {}
```

it is working well but it seems very primitive and i don't know if there's a better more practical way of doing it, maybe add it to the class or do it as a method?

if anyone knows please share with me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are using 2 different kind of objects. `$newKlassTest` of class `[SchulKlasse]` and `$test` which is a `PSObject`. I would suggest you to create a class `[Person]` or `[Lehrer]` and  let `[Schulklasse ].KlassenLehrer` be of class `[Lehrer]`. The class `[Lehrer]` schould have the properties you added to `$test`.
However you current constructor of the class `[SchulKlasse]` would require the `[Lehrer]`-Object to exist before the `[SchulKlasse]`.